# pgadmin Server connection error even if password is correct

Tags: postgresql, passwords, pgadmin

When i am trying to connect with server it shows me that the password is not correct even if i have entered right password.

Error:

> An error has occurred: 
>   09:54:58: Error: Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Allow access without a password, using this

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-TRUST

2. Login and change password for `postgres` user.
3. Then revert the changes done in step 1 and login with new password.